# How do I check a criteria in a discontinuous range of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a spreadsheet with the final marks and the average of those marks for all of the students in my class. Each subject has three columns below it: S1 (first semester), S2 (second semester) and G (general, average of S1 and S2).

Similarly, the average of the marks has three columns below it, S1 (the average of the final marks in the first semester), S2 (the average of the final marks in the second one) and G (average of the general final marks).

The average for a semester or the general average is calculated and displayed if all the final marks for that given semester are above 5. Otherwise, "CORIGENT" (Failed) is displayed instead. If I only had one column below each subject, I could use COUNTIF for the whole range of marks to check if there is any mark below 5 and display the average if it returned 0.

But in the actual situation, I have to "skip" two cells for every value added to the average and thus getting a discontinuous range of cells (C4, F4, I4 etc.) which COUNTIF, as far as I know, does not support. How can I replace this formula to address the issue? Spreadsheet with names removed here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AigPEMN6QqqIjA3cp0MrO0z4k6l7

Comment: you want to find a Average of S1 for Row 1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i have understood you question correctly this the answer you are looking for..

Place this formula in `BE4`

`=IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$BD$3,"S1",C4:BD4,">=6")=COUNTIF($C$3:$BD$3,"S1"),AVERAGEIFS(C4:BD4,$C$3:$BD$3,"S1",C4:BD4,">=6"),"CORIGENT")`

Updated..

Comment: Well, the formula also has to "dismiss" the students who got at least one failed subject (mark is under 5) and display "CORIGENT" (failed) instead of their average.

Comment: @AndreiCostescu let me add that to.. Will update the answer soon

Comment: Tested it, it works well, thanks a lot! I also added a bit to it so that it displays "N/A" if one or more cells is blank (if a final mark at one or more subjects is not yet known), and a bit that rounds down the average at 2 decimals (simply because that's the rule in the law of education, 9.505=9.50, not 9.51). Final formula:
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$BD$3;"S1";$C4:$BD4;"");"N/A";IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$BD$3;"S1";$C4:$BD4;">=5")=COUNTIF($C$3:$BD$3;"S1");AVERAGEIF($C$3:$BD$3;"S1";$C4:$BD4);"CORIGENT"))